# AutoIT, Using Variable in DirCopy Paths

Tags: string, variables, autoit, inputbox

I am attempting to use a Local variable in a DirCopy command but when I insert the `$Variable` into the `C:\Users\store$Variable\Desktop` path it attempts to read the path literally instead of using the $Variable.

The objective is to create a prompt for the Store number and insert that number into a bunch of DirCopy lines to ensure we get the profiles that contain only that number. The issue is that the profiles are one word, ex. store123, reciever123.

This is what I put together so far but I can't get it to take the variable in this way.

```
Local $STORE = InputBox ( "Store Number" , "What Store is This?" )
DirCopy ( "\\192.168.1.3\C$\Documents and Settings\store$STORE\Desktop" , "C:\Users\Store$STORE\desktop" )

DirCopy ( "\\192.168.1.3\c$\Documents and Settings\Profile$STORE\Desktop" , "C:\Users\Profile$STORE\Desktop")
```

Is there a formatting issue? or is this not possible in AutoIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1: Concatenation

In order to use Variables inside strings, you need to concatenate them, by using the `&` operator:

```
$nVar = 42
$sStr = "Hello, " & $nVar & "World!"
; $sStr will now hold: "Hello, 42World!"
```

### Method 2: Expansion

However, there is a `Opt()` [flag](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/AutoItSetOption.htm) `ExpandVarStrings` that enables inline variable use:

```
Opt("ExpandVarStrings", 1) ;0=don't expand, 1=do expand
$nVar = 42
$sStr = "Hello, $nVar$World!"
; $sStr contains: "Hello, 42World!"
```

Comment: As a short example, would this work? I tried and it didn't copy but I probably formatted this wrong.

Local $STORE = InputBox ( "Store Number" , "What Store is This?" )

DirCopy ( "C:\Store & $STORE" , "C:\Program Files\Store & $STORE" )

Where they enter 123 in the inputbox will it enter store123 into the path for dircopy?

Comment: You have to use _either_ one of the methods. Either you expand the strings and use them inline, or you concatenate them using &. I've edited my answer to reflect that.